# Translate JavaScript to Python API GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I found this code from Google Earth Engine.

```
/*
Author: Sofia Ermida (sofia.ermida@ipma.pt; @ermida_sofia)

this function mask clouds and cloud shadow using the Quality band

to call this function use:

var cloudmask = require('users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst:modules/cloudmask.js')
var TOAImageMasked = cloudmask.toa(image)
var SRImageMasked = cloudmask.sr(image)
or
var TOAcollectionMasked = ImageCollection.map(cloudmask.toa)
var SRcollectionMasked = ImageCollection.map(cloudmask.sr)


INPUTS:
        - image: <ee.Image>
                image for which clouds are masked 
OUTPUTS:
        - <ee.Image>
          the input image with updated mask
*/


// cloudmask for TOA data
exports.toa = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// cloudmask for SR data
exports.sr = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3)
    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5))
  return image.updateMask(mask.not());
};
```

I am interested in using it through the Python API, but I have a problem in the understanding of the syntaxis. I am totally novice working on JavaScript - Node JS and I have issues on how to implement this kind of statement: `exports.sr = function(image)` in Python. What would be the equivalence in the Python API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating the function definition syntax, JS

```
exports.sr = function(image) {
  ...
  return image.updateMask(mask.not());
};
```

corresponds to Python

```
def sr(image):
    ...
    return image.updateMask(mask.Not())
```

Note that there is a special consideration here: `not` is a keyword in Python, meaning that it can't be used as a method name, so the Earth Engine API uses the capitalized word `Not` in place of `not`. This also applies to the names `and` and `or`; other API methods are written with the same case in JavaScript and Python.

(In case you're wondering, there is no direct equivalent to `exports.` in Python, because when using modules in Python, there's no such thing as a non-exported symbol; everything defined at the top level of the file is "exported" as part of the module.)

Comment: How would you write this last part of the SR function in Python: return `image.updateMask(mask.not())`, particularly `mask.not()`. What exactly `.not()` does?

Comment: @Enricon Ah, there's a special case there which I didn't think to write about; because `not` is a keyword in Python, the EE API renames that method to `Not` for python only. So it's written `mask.Not()`. (What it does is invert a "boolean" image: all pixels with `0` values become `1` and all other pixels become `0`.) I've updated my answer to cover that situation.